# Notification alert not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)setAlarm:(id)sender {


[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"notificationIsActive"];
[defaults synchronize];

//self.message.text=@"Notifications Started";
NSTimeInterval interval;
interval = 10;
NSLog(@"time interval.....%f",interval);

UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification  alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:interval]; //Enter the time here in seconds.
localNotification.alertBody= @"This is message Users will see";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.repeatInterval= NSCalendarUnitDay;//NSCalendarUnitMinute;
//Repeating instructions here.
localNotification.soundName= UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

}
```

I use this code for notification alert with button click. This code works with my app for several times to give notification alert. But suddenly it stops working. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on iOS 10 & above, Apple Doc says

> `UILocalNotification` is deprecated in iOS 10. Use `UNNotificationRequest`
>   instead. A `UILocalNotification` object specifies a notification that an
>   app can schedule for presentation at a specific date and time.

Reference Links:

[UserNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications)

[Local Notification in iOS 10 for Objective-C and Swift 3](http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.ae/2016/07/local-notification-in-ios-10-for_31.html)

Comment: Another problem!!! I want to set a music which is longer than 30sec as notification soound. But after searching about this I came to know that it is not possible to add these type of music as notification sound. notification sound must be in 30sec longer otherwise it will not play music. Now how can I add more than 30sec longer music as notification sound?

Comment: "I have tested the maximum length of a push notification audio alert, which not surprisingly turned out to be 30 seconds. Any longer audio files will result in the built-in Tri-tone alert being played instead." - @smilespray

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it for iOS 10 and later.

```
UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
content.title = @"Don't forget";
content.body = @"Buy some milk";
content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
```

At a certain time

```
NSDateComponents* date = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    date.hour = 7;
    date.minute = 0;
    UNCalendarNotificationTrigger* trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger
           triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:date repeats:NO];

UNNotificationRequest* request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"MorningAlarm" content:content trigger:trigger];
```